# Vanishing locus of global section of invertible sheaf has codimension one

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, sheaf-theory, line-bundles

Let $X$ be a projective scheme over some field $k$. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be an ample invertible sheaf on $X$ and let $s \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ denote a global section of $\mathcal{L}$. Let $X_s = \{P \in X \mid s_P\mathcal{O}_{X,P} \cong \mathcal{L}_P\}$ be open. I am looking for a reference that $\operatorname{codim}(X\setminus X_s, X) \leq 1$ holds.

Comment: $X_s$ could be empty.

Comment: @Mohan Do you know a reference for the edited question/statement?

Comment: the problem at hand had nothing to do with the scheme being projective or not ..

Comment: @skeptic Okay. However, do you know a reference?

Comment: have a  look at krulls principal ideal theorem

Comment: $X_s$ is not empty is not enough, for example $X$ may be the disjoint union of two schemes, with $s$ not vanishing on any point of one component and zero on the other.

Comment: @Mohan You're right. I edited the question again.

Comment: @windsheaf  .. I repeat .. you should apply krulls PI theorem locally on affine open sets to conclude that the codimension is less than or equal to 1 ..